# Fullscreen background image buggy in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, background, border, fullscreen

I am trying to apply a full screen background image on one of my projects. It works fairly well in IE9 and Firefox but I´ve been struggling with an issue on Chrome because it adds some 1px border to the top and left.

Screenshot: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XcEY.jpg)

I tried to apply border:0; but still nothing.

```
   <img src="./images/highway.jpg" class="background-image" alt="background-image" />

    img.background-image {
    /* Set rules to fill background */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;

    /* Set up proportionate scaling */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Set up positioning */
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    }

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
    img.background-image {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
    }
}
```

Anyone has an idea of what might be causing this? Would appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, it is a bug of Chrome, they know that bug, but I think Google won't repair this bug, more than 10 versions since the bug appeared and they still didn't repaired...

If you change the size of the window magically the 1px dissapear (and reapear, depending of somethig inside Chrome)...

Try to put background-attachment: fixed, sometimes it resolves this bug (but your background loses the scroll movement).